# How to select multiple values for Drupal Facets (Facet API + Search API)

Tags: javascript, search

I am using Facet API + Search API to develop Filtering for the data within my site. I am also using Ajax Facet Filters to process the selection as soon as it's clicked.

It all came out great but there's one slight problem. I can only select one option per category. As soon as I select an option, all the inactive options hide and only the active (clicked one) shows.

I want the option to select multiple option but with my settings of Facet API & Search API, there seems to be no option.

Here's the picture to explain.
[image]

I'll be very thankful for any assistance.

Best.

- picture taken from :- https://drupal.org/node/1669600#comment-6190924

Comment: A note for aklumps answer. This is only possible if your backend is the solr api. It doesn't work with the search database api backend.

Answer (score 3):

I found the [first comment here](https://drupal.org/node/1679974) to answer this question.

> the OR operator is required for the facet instead of the default AND.
>   If the implementing search module you are using supports OR facets,
>   you will have an option in the "Global settings" fieldset located in
>   the bottom left hand corner of the facet's display settings form.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below step:

- Go to Administration -> Configuration -> Search and metadata
- Click on `Search api` link and it redirect you to `search api` page.
- Go to `facet` page using `facet` link from drop down.
- Select `Configure filters` from drop down in your active `filters` and it will redirect you to `filter` configuration page.
  [image: search filter]
- You can unchecked check-box `Hide items that do not change search result.` to show all filters.
  [image: search filter 2]

Kindly see that you can unchecked other check-boxes to configure different functionality.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Jayendra, but I can't see this option. What I see is shown here :- http://i.stack.imgur.com/gFP5T.png

Comment: May be you are using different version of `facet api` and `search api`. Have you checked each check-box? I think, it should be `do not display item that do not narrow results` check-box.